# UITextView in UIScrollView in UIView : IBOutlet Hierarchy?

Tags: uiscrollview, iboutlet

I have an UITextView inside an UIScrollView inside an UITextView.
And I want to add a "zoom skill" to UITextView.

I added <...UIScrollViewDelegate> in .h file.
I added this into .m file.

```
@synthesize myTextView;
@synthesize scrollView;

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)sv
{
    float zoomScale = sv.zoomScale;
    if (zoomScale < 3)
    {
        if(zoomScale < 0.5)
        {
            UIFont* myFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
            myTextView.font = myFont;
        }else{
            UIFont* myFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:(zoomScale * 12)];
            myTextView.font = myFont;
        }
        UIFont* myFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:36];
        myTextView.font = myFont;
    }
}
```

"scrollViewDidZoom" is never called.

I successfully add those objects with interface builder. To be honest I am a bit lost. 
I don't know how I should create outlets and delegates (with 3 level hierarchy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised there is a simple way to do it with UIPinchGestureRecognizer.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //...
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGest = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeTextViewFontSize:)];
    pinchGest.delegate = self;
    [myTextView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGest];
    [pinchGest release];
}

- (void)changeTextViewFontSize:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)p 
{
    CGFloat zoomVelocity = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)p velocity];
    UIFont *font = self.myTextView.font;
    CGFloat pointSize = font.pointSize;
    NSString *fontName = font.fontName;

    pointSize = ((zoomVelocity > 0) ? 1 : -1) * 1 + pointSize;

    if (pointSize < 8) pointSize = 8;
    if (pointSize > 32) pointSize = 32;

    self.myTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:pointSize];
}
```

Thank you Aral Balkan : http://aralbalkan.com/3831/